# Add DOM nodes as Any objects to JAXB class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a jaxb class with any elements:

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
protected List<Object> any;
```

I want to programmatically add DOM nodes to it, then marshall it to XML. Basically, what I've tried is creating a node and then adding it to the any list:

```
QName qn = new QName(...);
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
doc = f.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
Node node = doc.createElementNS(qn.getNamespaceURI(), qn.getLocalPart());
myJaxbClass.getAny().add(node);
```

Then I do the marhsalling:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.newDocument();
// Marshal the Object to a Document
JAXBContext jc2 = JAXBContext.newInstance(BookEntry.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jc2.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(book, document);
```

Marshalling the entire Jaxb class back to xml fails with an exception:

> com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "MyApp.MyJaxBClass.BookEntry" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]

How can I correctly add nodes to the any list programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a root XML element, which is basically mandatory for every valid XML document.
There are two ways of declaring root element I came with.

**A)** In code, create a root `JAXBElement` and pass it to marshaller:

```
QName qName = new QName("com.example.jaxb.model", "book-entry");
JAXBElement<BookEntry> root = new JAXBElement<BookEntry>(qName, BookEntry.class, book);
...
marshaller.marshal(root, document);
```

**B)** Annotate your model with `@XmlRootElement(...)`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "book-entry", namespace = "com.example.jaxb.model")
public class BookEntry { ... }
```

Both alternatives should produce same result.

Comment: Thank you! Wrapping my Jaxb class up in an JAXBElement did the trick. So  A) worked for me!